# JSViews template not updating when the underlying data changes

Tags: jquery, jsrender, jsviews, data-linking

I'm having an issue with a JSViews template updating when the underlying data changes. It involves a span that is data-linked using a converter function to the underlying data. When the underlying data changes after an async call back to the server, the span text is not updating.

Markup:

```
{^{for thedata.myarrayobject}}
    <span data-link="{myconverter:var1:} name{:'theName' + var2}"></span>
{{/for}}
```

Script:

```
$.views.converters({
    myconverter: function (val) {
        switch (val) {
            case 1: 
                return 'Test1'; 
                break;
            case 2: 
                return 'Test2';
                break;
            default: 
                return 'Default';
        }
    }
});
```

The span correctly displays on page load based on the values in thedata.myarrayobject. E.g. if we have:

```
thedata.myarrayobject[0].var1='1';
thedata.myarrayobject[0].var2='John';
thedata.myarrayobject[1].var1='2';
thedata.myarrayobject[1].var2='Matthew';
```

it will load as:

```
<span name="theNameJohn">Test1</span>
<span name="theNameMatthew">Test2</span>
```

However, if the underlying data changes after an async callback to:

```
thedata.myarrayobject[0].var1='2';
thedata.myarrayobject[0].var2='John';
thedata.myarrayobject[1].var1='1';
thedata.myarrayobject[1].var2='Matthew';
```

the span text is just staying the same.

I have debugged the js code and the underlying array parameter 'var1' is definitely being set to the new value. I have tried calling:

```
$.observable(thedata.myarrayobject).refresh(thedata.myarrayobject);
```

but to no avail.

I obviously want the span text to adjust as the underlying data changes - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show your code for how your are initially linking to the data, and then your code for updating to the new data. Ideally a jsfiddle - with a button calling your current code for updating to the new data? Then I'll take a look...

Comment: Hi @BorisMoore - jut to answer your question, I am using the link() method so the data-links should work.... but your second question about how I update the data has pointed me in the right direction. I'm doing it as above: just directly updating the parameter values in js. I;ve just tried it in an observable wrapper - and it has worked! I'll post it below. Is there any way I can give you some credit for this - I doubt I would have done it without your comment!

Comment: I added an answer to show some of the alternative ways you can merge data 'observably'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact to make an update, you need to choose your own strategy for merging the new data (e.g. from an Ajax call) with the previous data.

But any merge *must be done using the 'observable' APIs* - so that JsViews receives the data-linking update notifications and updates your UI.

So depending on your data and scenario, you could use any of the following kinds of update:

1. Change the leaf values one at a time:

   `$.observable(thedata.myarrayobject[0]).setProperty("var1", "2");`
2. Change the leaf values one object at a time:

   `$.observable(thedata.myarrayobject[0]).setProperty(newarrayobject[0]);`

   (This will pick up any modified properties)
3. Refresh the whole array with the new objects:

   `$.observable(thedata.myarrayobject).refresh(newarrayobject);`

   (This will copy the new objects/items over into the myarrayobject)
4. Update the myarrayobject with the new one:

   `$.observable(thedata).setProperty("myarrayobject", newarrayobject);`

   So here you are replacing the array with a new one...

Any or each of the above will trigger updates with the new data values.

Note that the above methods assume you have downloaded a new data array, `newarrayobject` which contains updated data to merge into your previous `myarrayobject`. You don't need to clone either the `newarrayobject` or the previous `myarrayobject`.

Answer (score 1):

Well after BorisMoore above asked a couple of questions... The way I was updating the data - just pushing it direct into the array parameters as above:

```
thedata.myarrayobject[0].var1='2';
thedata.myarrayobject[0].var2='John';
thedata.myarrayobject[1].var1='1';
thedata.myarrayobject[1].var2='Matthew';
```

was not working, and my call to $.observable(...).refresh(...) did not work because I was passing the same array: no changes were triggered to update to the markup.

Simply, I copied the array to a new one, updated the values, then called refresh, which works:

```
var myduparrayobject = thedata.myarrayobject.splice();

myduparrayobject [0].var1='2';
myduparrayobject [0].var2='John';
myduparrayobject [1].var1='1';
myduparrayobject [1].var2='Matthew';

$.observable(thedata.myarrayobject).refresh(myduparrayobject);
```

The problems:

1. Only observable changes to the array will be refreshed to the markup. Not just simply updating the object data as I thought it did.
2. $.observable(...).refresh(...) only works when a changed array to the referenced object is passed in. Passing the same referenced object like I did (even if it differs from what is being displayed in the markup) will not trigger changes to the template markup.